# how to find a document with mongodb by two or more mandatory subcondtions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

A possible Schema

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type : String},
    clubs: [{name: String}, {type : String}, {attending: boolean} ],
})
```

What I'm trying to do: find users that 'have' clubs of a certain type and with a certain value for attending:

```
User
   .find({ 'clubs.type': 'fightclub', 'clubs.attending': true }, 
       function(err, users){
           //users
       }
```

note: both the conditions must be met within a single 'club', it's not enough for the user to have 2 different clubs that each meet a single condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly what the [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch) query operator is for:

```
User.find({ clubs: {$elemMatch: {type: 'fightclub', attending: true }}}, 
   function(err, users){
       //users
   }
```